# Angular/NgRx - Combine 2 selectors in Guards

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a canActivate where i get 2 states

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

this.store.dispatch(new fromProjectActions.SelectProjectAction(43))

  combineLatest(
    this.store.pipe(
      select(fromProjectSelectors.getSelectedProject)
      ),
    this.store.pipe(select(fromUserSelectors.getUser))
    ).pipe(
      map(([project, user]) => {
        // Logic here
        // return true if project.creatorId === user.id
      })
    );
}
```

How can i do this knowing that the `getUser` is already available in the state, but the`getSelectedProject` it is necessary to dispatcher its action before

EDIT :

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromProjectActions.SelectProjectAction(43));

    combineLatest(
      this.store.pipe(
        select(fromProjectSelectors.getSelectedProject)
        ),
      this.store.pipe(select(fromUserSelectors.getUser))
      ).subscribe(([project, user]) => {
        // here the first time `project` is `null`, have to wait the 
          second time
        if (project) {
          if (project.id === user.id) {
            return of(true);
          } else {
            return of(false);
          }
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem here

Comment: @mouad I think you should provide on some more details on the scenario here. I kind of understand your issue but I am not fully confident about that so if you provide some more information maybe I can help.

Comment: @martin @kushagra I edited the question by adding another piece of code, the problem is that `project` is `null` in the first time.I understand that the question is not very clear, I did not find how given more detail, if you have any particular questions I can answer

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that `select(fromProjectSelectors.getSelectedProject)` emits a `null`, you could just filter it out:

```
combineLatest(
  this.store.pipe(
    select(fromProjectSelectors.getSelectedProject).pipe(
      filter(project => !!project))
    ),
  this.store.pipe(select(fromUserSelectors.getUser))
  ).subscribe( ...
```